# R using geocode with leafletProxy in Shiny to add markers and route

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I would like to use the new `leafletProxy` function to add markers (or circle markers) to a leaflet map in shiny as well as a route with the number of points on the route depending on a slider... Ideally I would also like the colour of the route to change if clicked on.

The markers are to be added by using the latitude and longitude gained from using the `geocode()` function in `ggmap`

Below is my attempt so far...but it doesn't seem to be working...Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated...

```
 # ui.R
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

header <- dashboardHeader(
  title = 'Simple dashbaord'
)
body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(
    column(width=12,
           leafletOutput('outputmap',height = 550)
    )
  )
)
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarSearchForm(textId = "origin.val",
                    buttonId = "button_click_count",
                    label = "Add marker"),
  sliderInput('num','Number of points:',min=1,max=3000,value=30)
  )


dashboardPage(
  header,
  sidebar,
  body
)
```

and

```
#server.R
require(shiny)
require(leaflet)
library(ggmap)
shinyServer(function(input,output){

  # Run Geocode only when button is clicked
  geocode_origin <- eventReactive(input$button_click_count,{
    geocode(input$origin.val)
  })

  # generate base leaflet map
  output$outputmap <- renderLeaflet({
    map <- leaflet() %>% addTiles()
    map
  })


 observeEvent(input$button_click_count,{
    v <- geocode(input$origin.val)
     leafletProxy('outputmap') %>% addCircleMarkers(lng=v$lon,lat=v$lat)
   })

  eventReactive(input$num, {
     num.points <- input$num
     lon.path <- c(v$lon,v$lon + cumsum(rnorm(num.points)))
     lat.path <- c(v$lat,v$lat + cumsum(rnorm(num.points)))
     renderLeaflet({
       leafletProxy('outputmap') %>% addPolylines(lng=lon.path,lat=lat.path)
     })
   })

    })
```

Comment: You need to add session parameter in server.R eg `shinyServer(function(input,output,session)`  + `leafletProxy('outputmap',session)`

Comment: What are the polylines supposed to represent? I have the circle markers working but the polyline logic is not quite right.

Comment: @on_the_shores_of_linux_sea: leafletProxy can actually infer the session, so it's optional.

Comment: @JoeCheng.. code is bit wrong here i guess `observeEvent(input$num, {
     num.points <- input$num
     v <- geocode(input$origin.val)
     lon.path <- c(v$lon,v$lon + cumsum(rnorm(num.points)))
     lat.path <- c(v$lat,v$lat + cumsum(rnorm(num.points)))
       leafletProxy('outputmap',session) %>% addPolylines(lng=lon.path,lat=lat.path)
   })
` this works

Comment: @JoeCheng the polylines are meant to be random paths...it is a mock example...i intend to use tracked GPS locations to give a route in my final output...but the aim is to have a route from the given lat lon that came from geocode...

Answer (score 0):

Working code

```
require(shiny)
require(leaflet)
library(ggmap)
shinyServer(function(input,output,session){

  # Run Geocode only when button is clicked
  geocode_origin <- eventReactive(input$button_click_count,{
    geocode(input$origin.val)
  })

  # generate base leaflet map
  output$outputmap <- renderLeaflet({
     map <- leaflet() %>% addTiles()
     map
  })


 observeEvent(input$button_click_count,{
    v <- geocode(input$origin.val)
     leafletProxy('outputmap',session) %>% addCircleMarkers(lng=v$lon,lat=v$lat)
  })

  observeEvent(input$num, {
  num.points <- input$num
  v <- geocode(input$origin.val)
  lon.path <- c(v$lon,v$lon + cumsum(rnorm(num.points)))
  lat.path <- c(v$lat,v$lat + cumsum(rnorm(num.points)))
   leafletProxy('outputmap',session) %>% addPolylines(lng=lon.path,lat=lat.path)
  })

})
```

Comment: @JoeCheng, can u suggest a way to clear the polylines and redraw new lines?

Comment: @JoeCheng, although not originally requested, a method to clear the polylines and redraw would be good....

Comment: Either `clearShapes()` before drawing, or, use the `layerId` argument. See new doc page here: http://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shiny.html

Comment: @JoeCheng thanks a lot.. btw updated site is kool.. Last day I did try with clearShapes and sometimes its getting executed after addPolylines.. is it a known issue?

Comment: @on_the_shores_of_linux_sea Thanks! The out-of-order execution bug was just fixed last week.